# How to create SQL language anonymous block in Snowflake with dynamic DDL statements

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, anonymous-function

I have over 2 dozen tasks in our Snowflake database, all having the names in a similar pattern ending with a number (example : TSK_x, where x = 1,2,...,27).
I am trying to trying to write a procedure or anonymous block in Snowflake (without using Javascript stored proc) to generate a descending order task number statements and execute them from inside the procedure like :

```
ALTER TASK TSK_27 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TSK_26 RESUME;
...
ALTER TASK TSK_1 RESUME;
```

The task (TSK_1) is the parent task and needs to be enabled last.

As a background, that script will be included in Jenkins as part of our build. Our Jenkins does not allow multiple SQL statements in one file and so I am thinking of a stored proc like the one mentioned above.
Any help/suggestion will be much appreciated. I am new to Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Query to "generate a descending order task number statements"

First execute -

```
show tasks;
```

| created_on | name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-02 12:53:23.662 -0700 | T1 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:11.032 -0700 | TASK_1 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:24:20.211 -0700 | TASK_10 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:17.883 -0700 | TASK_2 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:24:10.871 -0700 | TASK_2A | suspended |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:22.769 -0700 | TASK_3 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:26.497 -0700 | TASK_4 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:30.725 -0700 | TASK_5 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:34.765 -0700 | TASK_6 | started |
| 2022-06-13 20:11:38.313 -0700 | TASK_7 | started |

Query (change order clause as needed - add desc in end) -

```
select "name" as name,"state" from table(result_scan(LAST_QUERY_ID())) 
where regexp_like("name",'TASK_[[:digit:]]+$') 
order by substr("name",1,4), to_number(substr("name",6));
```

| NAME | state |
| --- | --- |
| TASK_1 | started |
| TASK_2 | started |
| TASK_3 | started |
| TASK_4 | started |
| TASK_5 | started |
| TASK_6 | started |
| TASK_7 | started |
| TASK_10 | started |

Anonymous procedure to set tasks to resume -

```
show tasks;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  p_tsk string;
  c1 CURSOR FOR select "name" as name from table(result_scan(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where regexp_like("name",'TASK_[[:digit:]]+$') order by substr("name",1,4), to_number(substr("name",6)) desc;
BEGIN
 
  for record in c1 do
  p_tsk:=record.name;
  execute immediate 'alter task '||:p_tsk ||' suspend';
  end for;
  RETURN p_tsk;
END;
$$
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This works in test. But coming from the Oracle world, I was thinking, I will have access to something like DBA_TASKS/ALL_TASKS/USER_TASKS view. The way my process is set up, I can't run "show tasks" and then the next block in the same Jenkins file. Meaning, the LAST_QUERY_ID() may not work all the time. 
Is there a system view that lists all the tasks and which can be invoked in your cursor query ?

Comment: select name from table(information_schema.task_history()) where name like 'TASK_%'; -- But this has limitations - FYI. Refer: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html#task-history

Answer (score 1):

To recursively resume all dependent tasks tied to a root task in a simple tree of tasks, query the [SYSTEM$TASK_DEPENDENTS_ENABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_task_dependents_enable.html) function rather than enabling each task individually (using ALTER TASK … RESUME).

Example:

```sql
    select system$task_dependents_enable('mydb.myschema.mytask');
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent command about disabling/suspending a task tree by calling the root task ? I saw the docs and found about : system$user_task_cancel_ongoing_executions ... but this will only work for tasks that are in "executing" status and not "started" status and yet to run.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know one like that.